# linux system crash after game exit

Tags: linux, multithreading, crash

I run my game on linux system of TV, when I exit game, the system will crash.

from the output log, I know my game has been quite, but system crash following.

the main function like below:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 ......

 SDL_Quit();

 printf("Log: exit end. \n);// it's printed on console
 return 0;
}
```

I can find the output log about Log: exit end. So the game has been exit right?

I found the game exit will **only** crash after create threads.

Here is the run function in thread below:

```
   while ( pThread->m_running )
    {
        string str;
        string cmdStr;

        if ( pThread->GetSendMsg(str, cmdStr) )
        {
            string returnStr = Connection::DealHttpSendMsg( str, cmdStr );

            pThread->AddReturnMsg( returnStr ); 

            haveData = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SDL_Delay(100);

            haveData = false;
        }
    }
```

My question is that if the `m_running` is alway true. so when I exit the game, the thread is still running. Will it cause the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will if that thread tries to access resources that are being simultaneously destroyed by the main thread.

Just quitting the app won't crash it if you have a worker thread that does nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* run_me(void*)
{
    while (1) 
    { 
       printf("Sleeping..\n");
       sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t my_thread;

    pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &run_me, NULL);
    sleep(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I updated the run function. Could you kindly help me to check. I'm a newer for programming. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I already stated the problem, but will try again. You are using `pThread` object inside the worker thread. I bet that this object is declared inside main() (but it's not shown on your code right now). When main() ends, everything it was allocated/constructed there is released. The problem is that your worker thread continues trying to reference an object that doesn't exist anymore. That's why its crashing.

Comment: Ideally you would change the state of `pThread->m_running`on the main() function before you `return 0;` so the worker thread will leave the *while* loop. It's also crucial to add a statement on main() and wait the worker thread to *join* before leaving the application. Check this reference to see how to wait for thread: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~travitch/pthreads_primer.html

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I think I got the reason.

Answer (score 0):

`return 0;` terminates only the main thread. Try to use exit(0) instead.

Comment: Do you mean when the main thread has exited and the sub thread is still running will cause crash?